# batch rename code needs modification

Tags: terminal

```
guppies_2018_02-01_001thrusday.jpg --> day001.jpg
guppies_2018_02-02_002friday.jpg --> day002.jpg
guppies_2018_02-03_003saturday.jpg --> day003.jpg
guppies_2018_02-04_004sunday.jpg --> day004.jpg
```

The above is what I want. I found a batch renaming code and tried to modify it. But have trouble removing the monday-sunday part.

```
for file in *.jpg; do echo $file day$(echo $file | cut -f3- -d- ); done
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your files have similar names with the same length text before the number, you could probably do something like this:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
dir /b *.jpg >dir.txt
for /f %%A in (dir.txt) do (
set var=%%A
set %var:~19%
set var=%var:~0,3%
ren "%%A" "Day%var%.jpg"
)
```

It removes the first 19 characters from the file name, then takes the next three and puts that between `Day` and `.jpg`.